# Idiomatic way of avoiding doing a nil? check

Tags: clojure

In this function there is a possibility that `to-right` will be nil, in which case the function should return false:

```
(defn has-children? [loc]
  (let [to-right (zip/right loc)]
    (and to-right (-> to-right zip/node vector?))))
```

While the above works fine, I suspect that there is a more idiomatic way of returning false when `to-right` is `nil`, yet otherwise using `to-right` for further investigation.

Comment: don't post an answer in your question. post your own answer on your question.

Comment: @Ven removed the answer in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you plan to thread along anyway, you can use `some->`. E.g.

```
(defn has-children? [loc]
  (some-> (zip/right loc) zip/node vector?))
```

Answer (score 6):

Clojure offers [`if-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let) as a shortcut for... Well, `if` and `let` (as well as [`when-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let) if your then branch has more than one form)

There's an else clause if you wish to use it. Otherwise you'll get `nil` as the else.

```
(if-let [t nil] t)
    nil

(if-let [t 1] t)
    1

(if-let [t nil] t 0)
    0

(when-let [t 3]
  (println t)
  (println (* 3 t))
3
9
```

Comment: And clearer for both of our examples would be to use `when-let`, sticking to the rule that you use `when` rather than `if` for situations where there is no `else` clause.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy added

Comment: Couldn't your first two examples be `when-let`, given that there is only one form after the *assignment vector*? Whenever I see an `if` I'm always looking for an else clause, and it is disconcerting not to find one.

Comment: Yes, they could both be. I only use `when` when I want to avoid an explicit `do`. It's more about style.